# Optimizing QuickSort partition for duplicates Java

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to optimize my partition algorithm to sort arrays full of duplicate elements faster since it goes in a sort of infinite loop if the array is ALL duplicates. The only thing I can think of is doing
firstunknown++ every time any adjacent elements are duplicates but I have no idea where or how to implement that in my code.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is no need to do the inner swap if the elements are equal. Change the swap condition from `>` to `>=`.

Comment: Duplicate elements are only an issue for Lomuto partition scheme. [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) will waste time swapping equal elements, but as the number of duplicates increases, the partitioning approaches the ideal split of 50% / 50%.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to remove duplicates, then do quick sort, and then add them back. The removal and addition of duplicates can be done in linear time.

**Removing duplicates**

This method removes duplicates from the given array and returns a map of <number in array, count>:

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> removeDuplicates(Integer[] arr) {
    
    LinkedList<Integer> duplicatesRemoved = new LinkedList<>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (Integer n: arr) {
        if (counts.containsKey(n)) {
            counts.put(n, counts.get(n)+1);
        } else {
            counts.put(n, 1);
            duplicatesRemoved.add(n);
        }
    }
    
    return duplicatesRemoved.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

**Adding duplicates back into sorted array**

Once you do your quicksort, you can add the duplicates back in (again, in linear time):

```java
public static Integer[] expand(Integer[] arr, HashMap<Integer, Integer> counts) {
      
    LinkedList<Integer> expanded = new LinkedList<>();
      
    for (Integer n: arr) {
        Integer count = counts.get(n);
        for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
            expanded.add(n);
        }
    }
      
    return expanded.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

This will save you complex work in handling duplicates within the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using 3-way partition quick sort? it works faster if there are duplicates.
https://medium.com/@nehasangeetajha/3-way-quick-sort-18d2dcc5b06b

```
private static void quickSort(int[] arr, int l,int r){
    if(l >= r){
        return;
    }
    int value = arr[l];
    int lt = l;
    int gt = r;
    int i = l+1;
    while(i <= gt){
        if(arr[i] < value){
            swap(arr, i++, lt++);
        }
        else if(arr[i] > value){
            swap(arr,i, gt--);
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    quickSort(arr, l, lt-1);
    quickSort(arr, gt+1, r);
}
```